# is there any way to use Variable instead path in java Scanner

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, jfilechooser

how to read file that assigned to reference variable selected using JFileChooser

```
package AnimeAid;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class ReadFile {
        private File ourFile;
              Scanner sc;

        public ReadFile() {
            this.sc = new Scanner(new File(ourFile);
        }

            }
```

Comment: `Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(yourVariable));`? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: take look now it gives error what type of Variable should be there and what if you try to put method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> " because i am trying to select file using JFileChoosear "

The `JFileChooser` will return a `File` object if `APPROVE_OPTION` is the return value. You can use `chooser.getSelectedFile()` then pass it to the `Scanner`

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

File file = null;
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
}

try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    // read file
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Run this

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class TestFileChooser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

        File file = null;
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        }

        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i like to ask you is Console Class going to help me if i wanna to read only part of the file

Comment: @isslamakkilah I don't think I understand your question.

Comment: @isslamakkilah you should ask another question on this site, as your question is totally unrelated to this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in a string like so:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new file(new String("/path/to/file.txt));
```